# What is the system property 'tomcat.bind.address' for Tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat, bind, ip-address

In a Tomcat based project I maintain, I came across a strange system property in the `tomcat.conf` file named `tomcat.bind.address`. It is defined like below:

```
export IPADDR=...
export JAVA_OPTS=-Dtomcat.bind.address=$IPADDR ...
```

I can't seem to find this system property defined anywhere even by googling or searching in the official tomcat documentation.

Tomcat seems to honor this system property however.

Do you have any pointers to this property?

**Tomcat 7.0.47**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a figment of somebody's imagination. That string doesn't appear in the source code. I changed it to something impossible and Tomcat still worked as before: that proves it.

The bind-address is configured as the `address` attribute of a `Connector`.

Comment: It turned out to be a custom system property expanded in multiple `Connector` nodes.